# Display Slug in WordPress Admin Columns posts/products custom post type

Tags: wordpress, slug

I'v searched around a good bit and can't find anything but a plugin, which breaks WP.

I'm using WooCommerce, so a custom post type is involved.
In the Products list page, I'd like to add a new Column, that displays the Slug of each product url next to each product.

I found a way to show the ID really easy, but not the slug.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First you want to add a slug column after the product name.

```
// Add product slug column after product name
function add_product_slug_column_heading( $columns ) {
    $slug_column = array(
        'product_slug' => __( 'Slug' )
    );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 3, true ) + $slug_column + array_slice( $columns, 3, count( $columns ) - 1, true );

    return $columns;
}
```

Then use the manage_product_posts_custom_column filter to display the slug value.

```
// Display product slug
function add_product_slug_column_value( $column_name, $id ) {
    if ( 'product_slug' == $column_name ) {
        echo get_post_field( 'post_name', $id, 'raw' );
    }
}
add_action( "manage_product_posts_custom_column", 'add_product_slug_column_value', 10, 2 );
```

**No coding solution**

If you're just looking for a quick solution without coding you could use [admin columns](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/), completely free. It allows you to add the same slug column with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact working code:

```
// Add product slug column after product name
    function add_product_slug_column_heading( $columns ) {
        $slug_column = array(
            'product_slug' => __( 'Slug' )
        );
        $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 3, true ) + $slug_column + array_slice( $columns, 3, count( $columns ) - 1, true );

        return $columns;
    }
    add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns','add_product_slug_column_heading');

    // Display product slug
    function add_product_slug_column_value( $column_name, $id ) {
        if ( 'product_slug' == $column_name ) {
            echo get_post_field( 'post_name', $id, 'raw' );
        }
    }
    add_action( "manage_product_posts_custom_column", 'add_product_slug_column_value', 10, 2 );
```